# Does SriVaishnavite scripture claim Lakshmi's superiority over Parvati and Saraswati?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, lakshmi

They have voluminous arguments for Vishnu's superiority over other male deities, but if I recall correctly, they also claim Lakshmi's superiority over female deities.

Is there Srivaishnavite scripture that claims this?

Comment: This is an issue that Thenkalais and Vadakalais disagree about.  Thenkalais believe Lakshmi is a Jiva, whereas Vadakalais believe she is Paramatma just like Vishnu.  But even Thenkalais believe Lakshmi is a Nitya Suri, and not a Baddha Jiva like Saraswati and Parvati.

Comment: Yes, as I said even Thenkalais view Lakshmi as a Nitya Suri, an eternally liberated soul, as opposed to Saraswati and Parvati who are Baddha Jivas, souls who still need to attain Moksha.  And Vadakalais accord Lakshmi even a higher status than what Thenkalais accord her.

Comment: Your question is having anwer if Narayana is supreme over all deity similarly Lakhsmi had to be supreme over all female, male deities.. its pure logic deduction.. in tartamya.. we see Lakshmi is extension of Narayana but not equal to naryana.. But Lakshmi is not Jiva,

Comment: In the Vadakalai tradition, there is really no separability of Vishnu and Lakshmi. the Pancharatra Agama says - "This is a subtle pair that defines mutual or reciprocal dependence". Therefore as Vadakalais/Pancharatrins consider Sriman Narayana as Parabrahman, the superlative nature of Lakshmi is implied.  Everybody is a jivatma except Lakshmi-Narayana. There is no need to explicitly state Lakshmi is superior to other gods (male or female). (I don't doubt that there are verses to that effect but merely saying that there is no need to base the superiority of Lakshmi just on those verses).

Comment: Since Lakshmi and Narayana are inseparable they were their before creation, will be there after dissolution.. In Ramayana we see the story that sita was taken away, in real sense where ever Narayana is there Lakshmi should be there. so Rama never get separated from Sita.. Sita that was taken by Ravana is Maya Sita

Comment: I am looking for something with the dignity and gravitas of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27071/what-scriptures-describe-shiva-discussing-selling-salt-in-the-banasura-story and I distinctly remember reading something like that somewhere @hashable

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Vedanta Desikan's Sri-stuti:

https://www.sadagopan.org/pdfuploads/Sri%20Stuti%20-%20VS.pdf

59 SRI STHUTHI SLOKAM 12

> AasamsAram vithathamakhilam vAngmayam yadhvibhUthi: 
>   yadhbhrUbhangAth kusumadhanusha: kimkarO MerudhanvA
>   yasyAm nithyam nayana sathakai: yEkalakshyO MahEndhra:
>   PadhmE thAsAm pariNathirasou bhAva lESai:Thvadheeyai:
>
> Meaning according to Dr. M.NarasimhAchAry: **Sarasvathy, Parvathy and Sachi are but modifications of minute particles of Your own graceful will.**
>
> Meaning   according   to   Vaikunta   Vaasi   Villivalam   NaarAyaNAcchAr   Swamy: The  Iswaryam  of  knowledge  (VidhyA=Kalvi)  that  is  spread  all  around  the  world  is  under the influence of Saraswathi DEvi, the consort of Brahma Devan; Lord SivA, the husband  of  Paarvathi  is  subservient  to  Manmathan  fearing  the  raising  of  the  eye  brows  of  His  consort.  Indhran  is  wide  awake  with  all  his  hundreds  of  eyes  and  is  looking  alertly  for  the  hints  form  his  Devi,  SaamrAjya  Lakshmi,  IndhrANi  .**Oh  MahA Lakshmi! The greatness (Mahimai) of Saraswathi, Parvathi and Indhran's wife are  nothing  but  specks  form  the  power  of   Your   anugraha   sankalpam   (Volition,   Sakthi).**

Comment: I think this is common. Trigunatitaa is the abode of the gunatmikaas.